# ON / OFF Button toggles multiple times

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit

I trie to create an ON / OFF button for the mute / unmute sound button :

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let resizeAction = SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.05)

            let fadeAnimation = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.whiteColor(), duration: 0.4)            

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == soundOnButton {

                soundOnButton.removeFromParent()
                self.addChild(soundOffButton)
                println("test 1")

            }


            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == soundOffButton {


                soundOffButton.removeFromParent()
                self.addChild(soundOnButton)
                println("test 2")


            }

        }

 }
```

But nothing happened, because when I touch the button, it is removed and the OFF button is added, but the application detect that I touch the OFF button, so it remove it and add the ON button, like an infinite loop !

Someone has a solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: You haven't written the code to remove the off button. how do you know its an infinite loop? put a `println("looping")` inside `for` loop to check if its an infinite loop.

Comment: Sorry i forgot this but it's the same thing for it, OFF is removed, ON is added !

Comment: could you please update the code here with both conditions?

Comment: I added println("test 1") to the first condition and println("test 2") to the second condition, and when I touch the button, the two "test" are displayed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `else if` in your `if` conditions. Otherwise both conditions will be executed. This is why your code fails. When the first condition is executed you place the `soundOffButton` instead of `soundOnButton`. When the executing reaches the second condition, the node at the point is `soundOffButton`, so again the buttons are interchanged. Using `else if`ensure that only one condition is executed at a time.

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === soundOnButton {

    soundOnButton.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(soundOffButton)
    println("test 1")

}
else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === soundOffButton { // Changed line
    soundOffButton.removeFromParent()
    self.addChild(soundOnButton)
    println("test 2")
}
```

Comment: When I click the sound ON button, it is removed and the OFF button is added, but when I click on the OFF button, the application crash !

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: 2015-02-19 10:58:38.616 MyApp[4210:780934] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'MS-SOFFB' (300 x 300)] position:{333.5, 93.75} size:{66.699996948242188, 66.699996948242188} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184dea59c 0x1955400e4 0x184dea4dc 0x1894200fc 0x1001abd4c 0x1001ac000 0x18940de04 0x1895d035c 0x1895c98b0 0x18959cfa8 0x18983bf58 0x18959b510 0x184da29ec 0x184da1c90 0x184d9fd40..... Etc and the AppDelegate.swift is showed

Comment: It think the sound ON button has already a parent, so it crash

Comment: try my new code. use the `===` operator instead of `==`.

Comment: It works very well, thank you ! But what is    ===     ?

Comment: It is used to check whether both refers to the same object.